# Is there any sort of of BluetoothKit for watchOS that you can import that checks Bluetooth connection status and other Bluetooth related functions

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos

I’m a beginner to swift and was wondering if there was anyway to check Bluetooth connection status from a watchOS app. For example can I check how strong weak or nonexistent the Bluetooth connection to my phone is from a watchOS app.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Have you looked anywhere for an answer? For example, in the Apple API documentation? Did you find something there that has information that isn't clear to you? Did you find nothing there?

Comment: @Douglas Lovell I really mean I am a beginner I have searched and continue to search through the api docs and other resources but it doesn’t really make sense to me. Is there one specific method I am missing or not understanding that does what I am asking? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry. I don't have an answer. Only picked this up in moderation. You could say, for example, that you looked at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit and aren't sure whether any of these classes apply. Or that you're not sure where to go after reading this overview https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_an_effective_watchos_experience/setting_up_a_watchos_project  in order to connect to an iOS app running on the phone. Other than this, I don't have direct experience with watchOS in order to help. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Bluetooth is the framework for Bluetooth-related functions for external devices. For checking the connection to the paired iPhone specifically, this is done through the isReachable instance property in the Watch Connectivity framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-isreachable.